# PHP socket Listening loop

Tags: php, sockets, networking, tcp

With the following code, I can receive 1 request and write it:

```
function listen()
{
    // Set time limit to indefinite execution
    set_time_limit (0);

    // Set the ip and port we will listen on
    $address = 'XX.XX.XX.XXX';
    $port = XXXX;

    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    $bind = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);

    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);

    /* Accept incoming requests and handle them as child processes */
    $client = socket_accept($sock);

    // Read the input from the client &#8211; 1024 bytes
    $input = socket_read($client, 2024);

    // Strip all white spaces from input
    echo $input;

    // Close the master sockets
    $close = socket_close($sock);

    var_dump($close);
}

listen();
```

But it close automatically listening once it received 1 packet. I need to keep receiving packets until an exit or any close command is received.

How should I go about changing the code above to make this function into a loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
set_time_limit (0);

$address = '46.49.41.188';

$port = 7777;
$con = 1;
$word = "";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$bind = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);

socket_listen($sock);

while ($con == 1)
{
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client, 2024);

    if ($input == 'exit') 
    {
        $close = socket_close($sock);
        $con = 0;
    }

    if($con == 1)
    {
        $word .= $input;
    }
}

echo $word;
```

If request will be exit listening will closed. That method was tested :) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function listen(){
// Set the ip and port we will listen on
$address = 'XX.XX.XX.XXX';
$port = XXXX;
// Create a TCP Stream socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
// Bind the socket to an address/port
$bind = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
// Start listening for connections
socket_listen($sock);
/* Accept incoming requests and handle them as child processes */
$client = socket_accept($sock);
// Read the input from the client &#8211; 1024 bytes
$input = socket_read($client, 2024);
// Strip all white spaces from input
echo $input;
// Close the master sockets
$close = socket_close($sock);
var_dump($close);
listen();
}
set_time_limit (0);
listen();
```

Comment: at first thanks for the answer :)... i will try this example but problem is that: socket_close can't close socket quickly. i have one example how to make my code into loop. i will write that code.