# How to create a persistant php listening server

Tags: php, tcplistener

I have some embedded devices which connect to their sever (supplied software for windows) running on port 6000.

I'm confused as to how this works as my understanding is that when a tcp connection is made on a port, that's it, the port is occupied an no other connections can be made.

But I guess this logic is wrong as multiple devices can connect to their server software just as a web server can accept multiple connections on port 80.

When I run netcat on an ubuntu server with the command `nc -l -k 6000` it seems to do what I want, I can see the messages coming in one after another from multiple devices.

From the netcat manual:

```
 -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its cur-
         rent connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option
         without the -l option.
```

I tried to achieve a similar scenario with php but I failed. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

$address = "0.0.0.0";
$port = 6000;
$mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($mysock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
socket_listen($mysock, 5);
$client = socket_accept($mysock);
while (true) {
    $input = socket_read($client, 1);
    echo $input;
}

?>
```

I can see the first message from the first device that connects but after that nothing. Also this seems to be the wrong approach as the while loop causes high cpu usage.

Note I'm running the php script at the command line on an ubuntu server.

I realize that this code will only accept one client, but how can I change it so that it will behave like nc and accept multiple connections. Sorry if the question seems vague, I really don't know where to begin. Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you send your data? Are you aware that you only accept one client? If you disconnect with that one client you end up in an dead lock.

Comment: I have no control over the data being sent, the clients are embedded linux devices which output messages periodically by connecting to a host on port 6000

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13000206/894872, loop until you want to terminate, loop over accept!